# phpMyAdmin: Exporting results of query with temporary tables

Tags: phpmyadmin, export-to-csv

I have a simple query that creates a temporary table and then a second query that appends new information into that same temporary table. I then want to be able to export this new table to a CSV file all in phpMyAdmin.

If I run the query it works fine and the results are displayed on the screen. However, I then want to immediately export those results to a CSV file but instead pushing the Export button opens up my second query in the Export screen and the fails. I'm sure this is a result of the temporary table disappearing but I thought they only disappeared at the end of the session.

Any clues as to what I can do to keep the temporary table around long enough to export the results?

Comment: Maybe you are confusing the end of phpMyAdmin's session with the end of the MySQL session; I believe that the MySQL session has already been reached when the first phpMyAdmin's operation stopped. So, do not use a temporary table.

Comment: Thanks Marc. That certainly sounds like the problem.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: I cannot think of a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that did the trick for me is to add a LIMIT to the query referencing the temporary table, so it would show more than the default of 25 records, and then copy-paste the contents from the resulting table in phpMyAdmin into a spreadsheet application.